# Receiving complete message from TCP socket

Tags: objective-c, sockets, tcp, nsstring, nsdata

I read data from a TCP socket connection, but the server sends me \0 from time to time (which would mark the end of a message). Thus, I do not get the rest of the message.

I read like this:

```
uint8_t buf[tcpBufferSize];
unsigned int len = 0;

len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:tcpBufferSize];

if(len > 0) {
    NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    [data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //here s will be only the part before the \0

    [s release];
    [data release];
}
```

for example, if the server sends abc\0de y will only get abc since the \0 marks the end.

How could I receive the whole message??

Comment: I don't know about anything about Objective C, but it looks like you're trying to stuff binary data into a data type that's built to handle strings (`NSString`). That is a bad idea in most languages (except those that don't make that distinction) and is most likely the source of your problem.

Comment: Also, please note that there's no such thing as a "message" at the TCP/IP level. It's simply a stream of bytes. If you want to send separate messages you need some way to communicate the start and end of each message inside the byte stream (either via special markers, or by sending a header with the length of the message, or ...).

Comment: @Joachim: I think the OP was talking about the other kind of message, the missive kind, not the network transport kind.

Comment: @dreamlax: what are you talking about? No kind of message exists on that leve, unless you make it exist in code. And that code doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: With message I meant a complete command sent by the server. In my case it is a complete xml node teminated by a \0, such as "<userleft />\0" or "<userlist><user nick="bort"></userlist>\0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have received the entire message. A string is for holding text, not byte data. If you want to keep all the data including the null character, you need to leave it as an `NSData` object. If you want to extract certain bytes and interpret them as text, you'll have to implement that yourself.